# Rabbit MQ heartbeat configuration not reflected using java

Tags: java, rabbitmq

We are trying to set the requestedHeartbeat value using

```js
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
        host="#{rabbitmq.hostname}" username="#{rabbitmq.username}"
        password="#{rabbitmq.password}" virtual-host="#{rabbitmq.virtualhost}"
        publisher-confirms="false" publisher-returns="false" requested-heartbeat="120" port="#{rabbitmq.port}"/>
```

we create a consumer object using

```js
AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/consumer_context.xml"); 
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = context.getBean(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.class);
```

container.connectionFactory.rabbitConnectionFactory has the value as 120

But when we check the connections heartbeat in RabbitMQ UI, it shows the value as 60.

Could any one please suggest what am i missing ?

I tried even with spring.rabbitmq.requested-heartbeat in application.properties as well. It did not work.

We are using spring-rabbit 2.1.8
RabbitMQ 3.7.15 Erlang 22.0.4

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ config also has a heartbeat value, so you might want to change that too.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html
*Value representing the heartbeat timeout suggested by the server during connection parameter negotiation. If set to 0 on both ends, heartbeats are disabled (this is not recommended). See the Heartbeats guide for details.*
Default:

```
heartbeat = 60
```

https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html#using-heartbeats-in-java
*Note that in case RabbitMQ server has a non-zero heartbeat timeout configured (which is the default in versions starting with 3.6.x), the client can only lower the value but not increase it.*

Comment: Server has no explicit value configured. Assuming if it is default 60 Seconds. When we try to connect with python code. It is able to set heartbeat as 120 seconds.